# When was it decided to make the Ancient Humans?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis

When Jack O'Neill went to the Asgard in SG1 S2E16 - The Fifth Race, the Asgardians didn't seem to recognise a member of the race of the Ancients. This makes me believe that it was only later decided that the Ancients are Human - or vice versa, the Humans are of Ancient descent.

Also with the Asgardians mentioning that the Humans have taken the first steps towards becoming the Fifth Race doesn't seem like they know that Humans have it "in them" to become a member of this pact.

So, at what point was it decided that Ancients are Human?

Comment: What makes you think that the Asgard didn't immediately recognise Jack as a modern human (as opposed to an Ancient, a race that the Asgard believe to be extinct)?

Comment: @Valorum It just seems like at that point, it hasn't been fixed that the Ancients are Human. It just feels like "they didn't know at that point that Humans are descendants of the Ancients".

Comment: Didn't the Ancients and humans evolve in separate galaxies?

Comment: Humans aren't descendants of Ancients. They are the "second evolution" of Ancients. That's why only some people (eg Jack) have the Ancient gene.

Comment: Thor, and I believe Loki, mention that they have been studying Humanity on Earth for a long time. Since it is implied that Thor knew the ancients, or at least some of them, and he has seen humans, it is a good bet that they knew humanity was a direct descendant/second evolution of the Ancients.

Comment: I see no evidence they didn't "recognise" what Jack was. Also, Ancients weren't humans. They were Ancients.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings If the answer is "From the beginning", that's fine with me. I couldn't find any details on it so decided to ask here.

Comment: I'm talking about the premise of your question.

Answer (score 5):

Jack O'Neill is a human with the Ancient Technology Activation gene. The Ancients presumably had other genes that humans don't have, given that they had more powerful brains, telekinesis, and other magical abilities.

The Asgard helping O'Neill presumably can't read his DNA, but they know he is not an Ancient because:

- O'Neill is sick and needs the Asgards' help. If he were an Ancient, using the device that downloaded the Ancient knowledge into his head wouldn't have made him sick.
- The Ancients are gone. We find a few Ancients here and there in other episodes of Stargate SG-1 and Stargate Atlantis, but it's a strong assumption that any human-looking visitor is a human and not an Ancient.

Comment: It does not really answer the question if it was already decided to make humans the second evolution of the Ancients or if that decision was taken later. Back on earth, the team assumes that Teal'C didn't get the knowledge because he has a symbiont. So, it could still be that they hadn't decided at that point that Ancients are evolved humans.